# Dart VM service client

Tags: java, dart

I'm trying to get a simple TCP client going that can
connect to the Dart VM service, send a request and get a response.

I've tried it with and without `connect()`.

The other question I have is what's the best Dart command
to "start" the VM service so that it's listening for requests?
With possibly giving what host and port to use, if needed.

Commands like `--observe` or `--enable-vm-service` are for the Observatory and I don't need that.

I've been using this
but I'm not sure what host and port it's using by default for that.

```
dart --pause_isolates_on_start bicycle.dart
```

So far, after I run the Dart command and run the client,
I get:

```
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

or it seems to send the request, but it just gets back "`-1`".

So what Dart command should I be using and what changes do I need to
make to be able to get a response back from the VM service?

I need to be able to do the client in Java and not Dart.

UPDATE:

Is the problem that the Dart VM service is using WebSockets and that
isn't compatible with Java Socket I/O?

It's looking like it does need to connect via a WebSocket, so I'm
looking into trying to get that to build and try it.

Thanks!!

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class DartTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

Socket socket = null;
InetAddress inetAddress = null;
InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = null;
OutputStream os = null;
InputStream is = null;
byte[] outBuf;
byte[] inBuf;
byte[] zeroDzeroAspaces = {(byte)0x0d, (byte)0x0a, (byte)0x20, (byte)0x20};
String sZeroDzeroAspaces = new String(zeroDzeroAspaces);
byte[] zeroDzeroA = {(byte)0x0d, (byte)0x0a};
String sZeroDzeroA = new String(zeroDzeroA);

int iAvail;
int iByte;
int iReadBytes;
StringBuffer readSb = new StringBuffer();

String sHost = "127.0.0.1";
int iPort = 8181;

try
{
    //inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(sHost, iPort);

    socket = new Socket(sHost, iPort);
    //socket = new Socket();
    //socket.connect((SocketAddress)inetSocketAddress);

    os = socket.getOutputStream();
    is = socket.getInputStream();

    StringBuffer outSb = new StringBuffer();

    outSb.append("{");
    outSb.append(sZeroDzeroAspaces);
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append("jsonrpc");
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append(": ");
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append("2.0");
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append(",");
    outSb.append(sZeroDzeroAspaces);
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append("method");
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append(": ");
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append("getVersion");
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append(",");
    outSb.append(sZeroDzeroAspaces);
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append("params");
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append(": {},");
    outSb.append(sZeroDzeroAspaces);
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append("id");
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append(": ");
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append("1");
    outSb.append((char)0x22);
    outSb.append(sZeroDzeroA);
    outSb.append("}");

    //System.out.println("outSb: '"+outSb.toString()+"'");

    outBuf = outSb.toString().getBytes();
    os.write(outBuf);
    os.flush();

    while ( true )
    {

        iByte = is.read();
        System.out.println("iByte: "+iByte);
        if ( iByte == -1 )
            break;

        readSb.append((char)iByte);
    }

    System.out.println("readSb: '"+readSb.toString()+"'");

    if ( socket != null )
        socket.close();

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Exception: "+e.toString());
}
}
}
```

Comment: RE: Is the problem that the Dart VM service is using WebSockets and that isn't compatible with Java Socket I/O? Our IntelliJ plugin uses Java to connect to Dart's service protocol, so I'm guessing there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Using WebSockets was the main thing, trying to connect to
the VM service/Observatory using "regular" Socket TCP
wasn't going to work.

Then the next roadblock came when the WebSocket server handshake
was failing when it would return "200 OK" instead of "101" to "Upgrade".

Then I was looking at the intelliJ plugin code, to see how they connected, and they used "ws://localhost:8181/ws", I was trying to use
"ws://localhost:8181", and once I used that, the handshake went through!!

When it worked I was using:

dart --enable-vm-service --pause_isolates_on_start bicycle.dart

I'm not sure who I'm actually connected to, the Observatory,
or the VM service, but at least I've finally gotten to the point
where I can try to send a request, and possibly get a reply.